# Python RTF Multi Column layout

Tags: python, rtf

Can anybody reccomend a way of generating a multi column RTF document with python, i was going to use PyRTF but i cant find any documentation on how to set up columns. i think i might need to edit the modules source any reccomendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to patch it up quite easily after a few technical difficulties
http://www.importsoul.net/python/pyrtf/

Answer (score 1):

PyRTF is abandonware and doesn't realy have anything in the way of documentation other than the examples. I don't know about columns, but it does support tables so you might be able to achieve the layout you want that way.

Comment: Can you suggest any alternatives

Comment: pyrtf-ng on google code is more up to date, but doesn't appear to do columns and hasn't been updated in 6 months. .NET has good RTF support, so perhaps IronPython would be worth looking at if you're on Windows.

Comment: nah no good sorry as this will be running on a current django app, thanks for the help though, il have a play around in the source code and see how i go